# Live update the front end change of the Spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I work with a Spring boot project and the front-end is written in `HTML/CSS/JavaScript`. This is simple so far and the only issue I feel is every time I change the front-end, I need to close and restart the `IntelliJ` over and over again. This is annoying and seriously time-consuming. Ater reading some online posts, I made the following steps which seem that updating the backend is recognized to the program, but, the original need is still unsatisfied.

A. I use the maven dependency in the `POM` file,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

The doc says that the developer tools are automatically disabled when running a fully packaged application. If your application is launched using java -jar or if it's started using a special classloader, then it is considered a "production application". So, I have changed the packaging to the `war` file in the `POM` like `<packaging>war</packaging>`

Also, in the `IntelliJ` setting, I have changed to 
`Compiler -> make project automatically`

B. I added `LiveReload Chrome extension` to the browser. When I clicked on the icon, the seems to operate to refresh the page. But, the internal change of the `HTML` doesn't reflect the browser.

What do I need to do to Live update the front-end change of the Spring boot project to the Chrome browser? This will help a lot knowing, thanks.

Update

As someone asked, I plan to develop the front-end using the `thymeleaf` and have the dependency in the `POM` file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The `application.properties` file is provided below,

[image]

The cache for the `Thymeleaf` is provided as `false`.

`spring.thymeleaf.cache=false`

Comment: Are you using Thymeleaf?

Comment: I have the dependency and I plan to use. But, now the page is just a bootstrap template downloaded from the website.

Comment: When using Thymeleaf 'hot deploy' is just a matter of setting this property: `spring.thymeleaf.cache=false` and changes to your view layer (HTML, JS, CSS) will be deployed just by running a build within your IDE e.g. `SHIFT` + `F9` in IntelliJ.

Comment: I have done that

Comment: In your previous comment you wrote "I have the dependency and I plan to use" which makes me think that you are not yet using Thymeleaf and this property: `spring.thymeleaf.cache` will be irrelevant to you until you start using Thymeleaf.

Comment: there should be a way to track even if the changes are in normal HTML/CSS?JavaScript file

Comment: If you are already intending to use Thymeleaf (for which 'hot deploy' already works) then perhaps you should do that rather than losing time on working out how to get 'hot deploy' working for a solution which you intend to replace with Thymeleaf?

Comment: I mean just curious to know which might help me later and also, other in the forum.

Comment: You certainly don't need to restart Intellij. Perhaps you just need to rebuild the project: `SHIFT` + `F9` or `Build > Build Project`. I suspect this is different to `Compiler -> make project automatically` since it will copy resources to target location (which is what you want) in addition to compiling classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I find useful as suggested in the comment is to build the project again and then, refresh/ live update the page in the browser. In `Mac OS`, it will be `COMMAND + FN + F9` or using the GUI

[image]

You certainly don't need to restart the project which saves a lot of the time.